Flutter FirebaseAnalytics returns error while ios build
I am trying to use Firebase Analytics in my flutter project. I added it in pubspec.yaml file (firebase_analytics: ^11.3.6).
After I have tried to restart my app this error message shows up in console:
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Sim in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           915.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbols:

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Sim.

Exited (1).

I tried flutter clean, flutter pub get and delete Pods folder and pod install again but nothing changed. In android version, there is no problem when debugging.
This is flutter doctor -v result:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.5, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale en-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.24.5 on channel stable at /Users/tolgasmac/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision dec2ee5c1f (6 weeks ago), 2024-11-13 11:13:06 -0800
    • Engine revision a18df97ca5
    • Dart version 3.5.4
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/tolgasmac/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A507
    • CocoaPods version 1.16.2

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google
    Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.96.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.102.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 13 Sim (mobile)          • 1C5FCC10-9E0F-4862-8028-B748E5045F71 • ios          •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)                 • macos                                • darwin-arm64 • macOS 14.6.1 23G93
      darwin-arm64
    • Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad                • darwin       • macOS 14.6.1 23G93
      darwin-arm64

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

And also i tried to clear pod cache but again nothing changed. I am waiting for your helps.
